# Basic Rails - how do automatically assign a new database entry to an associated entry it belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, models

I'd like to automatically associate a new database entry with the database entry it belongs to without having to make a choice while on the form as the user can only come from the category page, so that once you're in a category and you decide to make a new entry within that category, the newly created entry is automatically within that category upon submission. Can anyone offer any help?

My models are as follows:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :guides

end


class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :ratings

  def average_rating
    average = ratings.inject(0.0){ |sum, el| sum + el.value }.to_f / ratings.size
    average.round(2)
  end

end
```

The link to create the new guide for the category is pretty standard, though I thought that adding an instance variable might automatically associate the entry with the category though it doesn't:

```
<%= link_to 'New Guide', new_guide_path(@category) %>
```

Here is the controller for the guide:

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_guide, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /guides
  # GET /guides.json
  def index
    @guides = Guide.all
  end

  # GET /guides/1
  # GET /guides/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /guides/new
  def new
    @guide = Guide.new
  end

  # GET /guides/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /guides
  # POST /guides.json
  def create
    @guide = Guide.new(guide_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guide.save
        format.html { redirect_to @guide, notice: 'Guide was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @guide }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @guide.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /guides/1
  # PATCH/PUT /guides/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @guide.update(guide_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @guide, notice: 'Guide was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @guide }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @guide.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /guides/1
  # DELETE /guides/1.json
  def destroy
    @guide.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to guides_url, notice: 'Guide was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_guide
      @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def guide_params
      params.require(:guide).permit(:name, :category_id, :user_id, :stepOneText, :stepOnePhoto, :stepTwoText, :stepTwoPhoto, :stepThreeText, :stepThreePhoto)
    end
end
```

Form is pretty standard too, is there anything I should put in here to automatically assign it to the category entry it belongs to?

```
<%= form_for(@guide) do |f| %>
  <% if @guide.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@guide.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this guide from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @guide.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepOneText %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepOneText %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepOnePhoto %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepOnePhoto %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepTwoText %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepTwoText %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepTwoPhoto %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepTwoPhoto %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepThreeText %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepThreeText %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stepThreePhoto %>
    <%= f.text_field :stepThreePhoto %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the associated user determines the category?  If so, could you use that information in the controller to set category when you create the guide?  Otherwise, how is the category determined?

Comment: When you assign @guide in your controller, you need to build it from the category. Something like `@guide = category.guides.build`. You will need to assign category first (e.g., `category = Category.find(params[:id])` if you are passing the id in to the controller). Would need to see the relevant controller and params to be more specific.

Comment: Have added the guide controller. Would love to see what you suggest. Will try to implement some of the above comment in the meantime. Cheers

Comment: What params are passed to the new method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, have edited in the controller above so you can have a look.

Comment: The params are the values passed to the controller that you can use to find  (in this case) the Category. You can see them in the output dumped to terminal if you are running on localhost. I don't have a ton of time right now, but check out this question/answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665546/rails-pass-parameter-from-view-to-controller). The one difference would be you would use the 'build' option to create a new @guide. By using nested routes, you will be getting the Category id in your params, which is what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you could go for something like a nested route here :

```
resources :categories do
  resources :guides
end
```

and then use your new route

```
<%= link_to 'New Guide', new_category_guide_path(@category) %>
```

This should make it easier to get the guide's category back when getting the form back.

Comment: Now getting a no method error on the following 

'  <strong>Guides:</strong>
  <p><% @category.guides.each do |guide| %> 
    <p><%= link_to guide.name, guide_path(guide) %><p>
  <% end %></p>'

Comment: Try changing `guide_path(guide)` to `category_guide_path(guide)`.

Comment: Not working either `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"guides", :format=>nil,`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a column on your guide table that stores category ID, and your routes are nested as has been recommended, you should be able to add

```
@guide.category_id = @category.id
```

To your guides controller create action. And in your form change the first line to

```
<%= form_for[@category, @guide] do |f| %>
```

Now this should work

```
<%= link_to 'new guide', new_category_guide_path(@category) %>
```

And the current category should be assigned to your guide when it's created.